# Trying to remove index.php from code igniter not working with post

Tags: php, codeigniter

Rewrite rule working fine, apart from when I post any forms - the url that the data gets posted to is domain/index.php/index.php/controller/method.

Any ideas? Already tried may responces on here.

HT Access:

```
    # rewrite rules
    RewriteEngine On

    # ditch index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This htaccess is fine for me, it is more the url you post to that should be a problem. Can we see the form ?

Comment: Your are using form helper right?

Comment: Can we see the form please? At least the action/target url?

Comment: Lol all people are getting hungry for this question!

Comment: Hi all,  yes that is the whole htaccess file. On mobile at the mo but the form is at www.gadoomph.org/contact thanks

Comment: what is the base url of your site.............

Comment: How are you generating the 'form' action url? Are you using base_url() or something similar? I reckon you are not supplying the right variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove index.php from $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; variable found in config.php file. full path application/config/config.php.

Replace

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

from

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Hope it will work for you.